# How to get the value of a variable from html page to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<script>
   var A = 10;
</script>
```

I want this variable " A " in the javascript file.  how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window object to access the element and store it in another variable

```js
var x=window.A
console.log(x)
```

```html
<html>
<head><script>
   var A = 10;
</script></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```